# How to exit if else and for loop in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, if-statement, break

I am planning to exit my if else or loop statement in Flutter when it detects there are duplicated item in my lists. But it does not work well when I put `break` in the if and else statement. When I put `break` in if, then the else statement will continue to execute even when the if statement had `break` the loop. If I put `break` in the else statement, then the if statement will not execute at all since the `break` in else statement will affect `i++`. While if I put `break` in both if and else statement, it shows my `i++` is dead code.

Here are the code:

```
  void addFavourite() {
    favouriteCountry.add(properties[0]['name']);
  }

  void checkDuplicates() {
    int length = favouriteCountry.length;
    String cName = properties[0]['name'];

    if (length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        String name = favouriteCountry[i];
        print(name);
        if (name == cName) {
          print(length);
          showDialog<void>(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text(
                    'Duplicated action, country already added to list.'),
                content: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: ListBody(
                    children: const <Widget>[
                      Text('You really liked this country huh?'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextButton(
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
          break;
        } else {
          addFavourite();
          displayAddFavourite();
          print("object");
        }
      }
    } else {
      addFavourite();
      displayAddFavourite();
      print("object1");
    }
  }
```

I tried to put i++ in both if and else statement, but it does not work. So if there is anything I can add into my code to make it work. Please feel free to enlighten me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a simplified example that demonstrates the problem and that shows what behavior you want? `break` will immediately break out of the current loop; it does not matter if it's within an `if` or `else` block.  You likely are not observing what you think you are (for example, perhaps `checkDuplicates` is called again after breaking out of the loop).

Comment: Have you tried using return instead of break? the downside of using return is that it will exit the whole function and not just the loop.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah exactly! The `checkDuplicate` did get called again.

Comment: @IttaiBarkai Yea I tried it, it will causes the `i++` to not work so its not suitable as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably consider using a `flag` and show the `dialog` accordingly.

```
void checkDuplicates() {
  int length = favouriteCountry.length;
  String cName = properties[0]['name'];
  bool foundDuplicate = false;          // set this flag

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    String name = favouriteCountry[i];
    print(name);
    if (name == cName) {
      foundDuplicate = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (foundDuplicate) {
    showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        // ...
      },
    );
  } else {
    addFavourite();
    displayAddFavourite();
    print("object");
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm!! Learnt a new thing today, thank you so much for your time and effort.